# Unix Wget | # in URL | Syntax Issue

Tags: shell, unix, tableau-api

what should be the wget command if the URL contain #

Ex of my url
https://tableau.abc.intranet/#/site/QQ/views/Myreport/DailyReport.csv

Command

`wget -P /temp "https://tableau.abc.intranet/#/site/QQ/views/Myreport/DailyReport.csv"`

however wget is considering the url till intrenet/ after that it is not taking .

Comment: tried %23 as well but not working

Comment: The part after the `#` is likely handled client side in JavaScript by the web app. You should see if there's a way to get a direct link to the file instead.

Comment: @sharanjain you can try to download the csv on your browser and go to your browser download page (ctrl + j on chrome) to checkout the csv download link, does it match this one ?

Comment: To quote https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment, with emphasis: *The fragment identifier functions differently to the rest of the URI: **its processing is exclusively client-sided with no participation from the web server**.* -- wget's job is to send things to the server and get its response back. The URI fragment is not sent to the server. Thus, anything in the URI fragment is not wget's (or curl's) business.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not reflect anything in wget not working-as-designed.